# Port forwarding in zte router F670L

Tags: xampp, portforwarding

Trying to post a website via port forwarding but everytime I use an open port check tool it says that the port cannot be reached. I was wondering if someone out there has done port forwarding in this router. Thank you.

These are the settings for my port forwarding:

- Protocol: TCP
- WAN host start & end IP: Blank
- WAN Start and End Port: 8080
- LAN host start and end port: 8080
- WAN Connection: TR069
- LAN host address: my IP

I have set up a static IP address, and even changed the port of httpd.exe to 8080 and 8081 (xampp) because I thought my ISP was blocking port 80.

Any type of help is appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

I was battling this over a month only to discover that I have a CGNAT (Carrier given NAT [NAT from ISP]) So no matter what settings I changed on my router my ports will never be opened.

Today finally my ISP removed the NAT from my account and I was able to proceed to open ports.
So I am sharing this info now for any others who may have difficulty opening their ports.

For the ZTE F670L GPON ONT router, you need to login as an admin:
Username: admin -
Password: Web@0063

Proceed to Internet in the main tab and select Security in the left panel then
in the sub tabs select Port Forwarding.
I also have DMZ enabled. Here are the screenshots of my settings.
(Please be sure that your PC/device IP is static)

Screenshot of my static IP on my PC
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9aGw.png

Screenshot of port forwarding settings for port 16000 UDP (I opened both TCP and UDP)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kv0V4.png

Screenshot of DMZ settings. (Not always necessary)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF0qR.png

If your ports are not opened after just the normal port forwarding settings, you can try to enable DMZ as in the above screenshot. If still no luck, contact your ISP and ask them to remove NAT from your account.

I hope this helps
I kept blaming my poor router when in fact it was just my ISP.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/jfS1Sqt , 
It says WAN Host IP addr is req. Even if I put my computer IP addr. in their or range 1-255 it won't work

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this problem was made a listener request in my case on Linux, using the following command "nc -l -p PORT", before that you need to set up correctly the port forwarding on the F670L, then you go to a web port checker and just fill with your ip, and the port that you opened.

It will work only with the first request, then the port will close.

Hope you can solve it